# Could we define an arity of a term in combinatory logic and consider some inference rule?

Tags: combinatory-logic

In computer science, we know a function has an arity. And we noticed the similarity between function and a term in combinatory logic, so could we define the arity of a term in combinatory logic? And also could we consider some inference rules?

By definition, we have:

$Ix \rightarrow x$

$Kxy \rightarrow x$

$Sxyz \rightarrow xz(yz)$

These definitions may lead us to think:

- arity of I is unary
- arity of K is binary
- arity of S is ternary

If these are held, we may say $\iota$ is an unary term where

$ \iota x \rightarrow xSK$

But it cannot easily judge that

- $\iota \iota \rightarrow I$, and then it is unary
- $\iota (\iota (\iota \iota)) \rightarrow K$, and then it is binary
- $\iota (\iota (\iota (\iota \iota))) \rightarrow S$, and then it is ternary

Comment: Your question is far from clear. What are you trying to achieve by classifying CL terms as unary, binary etc? What is $\iota$? Is it supposed to be (the translation into CL of) the $\lambda$-term $\lambda f.fSK$?

Comment: Hi, Rob, $\iota$ is a one-combinator basis of CL, and it is the $\lambda$-term $\lambda f . fSK$

Comment: Well, I think you've really answered your own question: it doesn't really make sense to assign rarities to CL terms: because (at least in untyped combinatory logic) you can apply any term to any other term. In typed combinatory logic, the types give a much stronger notion than arity that does make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the related untyped and typed theories.